# String.replace grouping, integers conflicts with replacement patterns

Tags: elixir

I want to add a digit to my replacement, however it seem to conflict with the replacement pattern.

ex.

```
# Wanted result "249,00"

"249,0" |> String.replace ~r/,(\d)$/, ",\\10"
# -> "249,"

# The closest i can get.

"249,0" |> String.replace ~r/,(\d)$/, ",\\1 0"
# -> "249,0 0"
```

How do i get "249,00" instead of "249,0 0"? My current solution is to do yet another replace, where i consume the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
"249,0" |> String.replace ~r/,(\d)$/, ",\\g{1}0"
```

I would love if you could send a pull request to Elixir docs so we can improve it. :)

Comment: Thank you Jose, i would love to. :-)